# Ruby/Paperclip: How to get missing.png to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am creating user avatars. I am having trouble getting the "missing.png" to show up. For users who decided not to upload a profile picture, I have created a default image to be displayed. Below is what I got so far. Please show me what I am doing wrong.

**user.rb**

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { large: "800x800>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "50x50>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**posts/index.html.erb** (Shows all posts by all users, for the moment)

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:medium)), user_path(post.user.username)) %>
```

**users/show.html.erb** (This is the user's profile page)

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

**"missing.png"**

Images: `app/assets/images/missing.png`

Thumb: `app/assets/images/thumb/missing.png`

Medium: `app/assets/images/medium/missing.png`

Large: `app/assets/images/large/missing.png`

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

Try:

```
default_url: "/:style/missing.png"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me.

Comment: @GVS, Do you have image for `missing.png` on the said urls?

Comment: Yes. If you mean did I also create a new path "app/assets/images/style/missing.png"